# UICollectionViewLayout 'locked' error message

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

After (successfully) calling

```
__weak typeof(self) wself = self;
[self.collectionView performBatchUpdates:^{
    [wself.collectionView.collectionViewLayout invalidateLayout];
    [wself.collectionView setCollectionViewLayout:self.layoutDeletion animated:YES];
        } completion:nil];
```

I receive the following error message:
`trying to load collection view layout data when layout is locked`

the operation works fine, except that one particular UICollectionViewCell not loading its subviews.
I have never seen this error message before, including google. Any ideas what might cause this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The error is being generated by calling `setCollectionViewLayout` within `performBatchUpdates`. It is unclear if this is expected behavior (a coding error) or a bug in iOS. You can report the issue to Apple, but in the meantime you should refactor to perform the layout change without batch updates. You can always use the completion handler to perform any additional updates to the collection view.

Comment: For me with iOS 9 to get rid of the warnings I needed to call `setCollectionViewLayout` in the completion block.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue on iOS 8… 
Actually, I just removed the performBatchUpdates: method and everything worked just fine for me !